# Error in fetching error message from en.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have included following code in my model

```
class MyDetail < MyBase
    validates :number, format: { with: /\A(?:[\- \+\(\)0-9])+\z/,  message: I18n.t('error.validation.number')}
end
```

and in my en.yml file given this error message

```
en:
    error:    
        validation:
          number: "Invalid number oasis."
```

but its showing message like this :

> Phone Invalid number oasis.

But I want to show error as Invalid number oasis. Please guideme how to solve this.

Comment: It looks to me like your translations are working fine. If the translations weren't working you'd get a different message--the default. But the validation message you see contains your .t text. I would look to see why the "Phone" text is being pre-pended.

Answer (score 0):

Translation files in rails need to start with the language code. Try this:

```
en:
  error:    
    validation:
      number: "Invalid number oasis."
```

Note: Ensure there is a newline character at the end of YML files, otherwise they sometimes don't parse.

Comment: It wasn't in your initial question, so it was a possibility.  Where is the en.yml file located? Have you got that location in config/initializers/i18_setup.rb? Usually you expect a line starting `I18n.load_path = `

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        my_detail:   #use my_base if you want it for all child
          attributes:
            number:  "Invalid number oasis."
```

here you can specifically mention model name with attribute to show error message .

Please read the following one to understand it

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on [so]. Please explain a little bit what is going on. Thanks.